# How to parse a specified class which extends a base class using Gson?

Tags: java, gson, config

Let's first state the (base) classes that are part of this:

```
// the data class. This contains our values
public class Data<T extends Annotation> {
    public transient final T info; // gson ignores transients
    public Data(Class<T> annotation) { info = getClass().getAnnotation(annotation); }
}

// the manager class, this contains numerous Data's
public class Manager<T> {
    protected final ArrayList<T> collection = new ArrayList<T>();
    public Collection<T> GetCollection() { return collection; }
}
```

Now suppose I've implemented the above classes in the following Manner:

```
// my implemented manager. It contains a bunch of MyBase objects
public class MyManager extends Manager<MyBase> {
    public MyManager() {
        collection.add(new MyCustomBase());
        // some more...
    }
}

public class MyBase extends MyData {
    // some stuff for my base, such as various methods for calculating and rendering
}

public MyData extends Data<MyData.MyInterface> {
    public String foo;
    MyData() {
        super(MyData.MyInterface.class);
        foo = info.foo(); // handle our interface variables, since interfaces cannot be directly modified
    }

    @Retention
    public @interface MyInterface {
        String foo();
    }
```

For sake of hopefully understandable code, my custom base looks like this:

```
@MyData.MyInterface(foo = "bar")
public class CustomBase extends MyBase {
    // other various methods for rendering and calculating, some events in here too
}
```

Now, in GSON, I'd like to print out the information from MyData. This is the way I've gone about trying to do it:

```
public class Config {
    // store the 'Managers' which we want to save the data of inside of an arrayList, and then iterate through them and their contents for 'Data', then just save it.
//...
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(myJSON);
for (Manager m : managerList) {
    for (Object o : m.GetCollection()) {
        Data d = (Data) o;
        // expected result, a json with "foo": bar
        writer.println(gson.toJson(d)); // this doesn't work, throws a stack overflow
    }

    writer.close();
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach is not working. It, for some weird reason, throws a Stack Overflow. What might be a better approach for this?

Edit: I won't handle the interface directly since foo, or any other values will change during the course of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to avoid this issue by making use of the @Expose annotation:

```
public MyData {
    @Expose public String foo;
}
```

Then, when creating the Gson using GsonBuilder, just use `excludeFieldWithoutExposeAnnotation()`.